# Tmux/Vim plugin that shows a list of open files

Tags: vim, tmux

When I have many vim files open in different tmux panes, it becomes difficult to keep track of where they all are. I would love to see a list of open tmux panes labeled with the filename of the vim file being edited. Does such a plugin exist? Is it possible to create one?

Comment: Why do you have several `vim` instances opened across different panes?  I hardly ever use `tabs` so why should one add another grouping level!? I always open new files with `vim --remote` so i have only one place to go...

Comment: I open many files so I can switch between them without having to close and reopen.

Comment: `vim` can do this perfectly for you. No need to waste memory. You should get used to `vim`'s concept of the buffer list. That makes switching really easy and you can enjoy working with 10+ files in one `vim` instance.

Comment: I have to agree. Using one instance of vim will increase your efficiency in the long run. Try something like ctrl-p or fuzzyfinder to move between files in vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such a plugin to work you would need all your vim instances to run as servers on the same machine in order to query all the visible instances for their bufferlist. This sounds like a pathetically complex solution to a really dumb problem, IMO.

Unless you have a very specific need you shouldn't run multiple vim instances. Vim is perfectly able to deal with dozens of files and has many plugins designed to make buffer management easier.

Start with :help buffers.

Also, tmux is a fine piece of software but you should probably take a moment to weight the complexity it adds to your setup and workflow against its actual benefits.

Answer (score 0):

```
tmux choose-window
```

will show the name of current directories of all buffers.

```
(0)  0: ssh  "u35@localhost:~"
(1)  1: vim- "u0_a105@android:~/K/20081121"
(2)  2: vim  "u0_a105@android:~/K/2014"
(3)  3: vim  "u0_a105@android:~/K/20120430"
(4)  4: bash* "u0_a105@android:~/K/20081121"
```

I personnaly use
    bind-key '"' choose-window

so that ^A" gives this list like screen did.

If you want to see the name of current file, you might configure vim to change the buffer name, as bash is doing.